# Html2pdf error displaying some images on pdf readers

Tags: php, macos, html2pdf

New here and I have a little problem :

I generate a pdf in php using simple code and html2pdf like this :

```
<img src="public/images/<?php echo $image ?>"/>
```

And the issue is that for some images (the only example I have are the screenshot images generated on mac OS), the images doesn't appears on the pdf when previewing it in other pdf reader that google chrome.

I tested if It was because the image name contained whitespaces : it's not.
Not an extension problem too, tested with jpg and png, both works, mac screenshot are png images.
The only notable difference between the images that are being displayed and the images that doesn't are the `color profile` announced in the "get info" on MacOS : the screenshots does have a `Color LCD` profile. It can be a hint on what the issue is.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Im not sure but HTML2PDF need the absolute path for the img src

Comment: Tell me, do you think that everybody has a `public/images` folder with your images in it?